# JsonSerializer not working for nested objects using GSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, android

I have a json object that looks like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1234
        ... 
        "photos": [
            {
                "url": "http://....."
                ...
            },
            {
                "url": "http://....."
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to write a custom deserializer for both `user` and `photos`.

so I have:

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private ArrayList<Photo> photos;
    ... 

    public static class Deserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {
        ... // does the custom serialization of the User object 
    }  
}

public class Photo {
    private String url;
    ... 

    public static class Deserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Photos> {
        ... // does the custom serialization of the Photo object 
    }  
}
```

and when initializing I do this:

```
new GsonBuilder()
   .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new User.Deserializer());
   .registerTypeAdapter(Photos.class, new Photos.Deserializer());
```

However, when i deserialize the `User` class, it hits the `User`'s deserializer but never hits the `Photo`'s deserializer. But if i get a json with the photo object not nested in the user json object like this:

```
{
    "photos": [
         {
             "url": "http://....."
              ...
         },
         {
             "url": "http://....."
              ...
         },
         {
             "url": "http://....."
              ...
         }
]
```

it will properly hit the `Photo`'s deserializer

Comment: Could you please tell why you need custom deserializers for this case?

Comment: The example I gave above was a very simple one. the objects i use in my app is much more complicated.

Comment: Hi, I saw your question at GitHub: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1034 -- could you please close it since you are aware of how Gson type adapters work now? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, there is a non-formal rule: once you declare a type adapter (or a (de)serializer that share the same concept in principle) for a *certain* type, then you have to manage its instantiation and its child fields yourself. Thus, when you deserialize the top-most `User`, its `id` and `photos` are deserialized on your own. Note that the `Photo.Deserializer` is invoked once you request for it explicitly like `gson.fromJson(..., Photo.class)` or apply it implicitly (for the latter Gson uses built-in strategies by default, please see `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` for example) via deserialization contexts. The same principle goes to `User` if you don't bind `User.Deserializer`, therefore Gson uses `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter<T>` that just iterates through all fields itself using reflection. Even shorter: Gson does not merge multiple strategies (at least by default), so you either delegate object construction and setting up to Gson, or instantiate it completely.

Knowing that, `User.Deserializer` can be implemented as the following:

```java
final class User {

    final long id;
    final List<Photo> photos;

    private User(final long id, final List<Photo> photos) {
        this.id = id;
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    static final class Deserializer
            implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

        private static final Type photoListType = new TypeToken<List<Photo>>() {
        }.getType();

        @Override
        public User deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            // Note that you must pick up properties first
            final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            return new User(
                    // And then delegate them to the deserialization context specifying the target type
                    context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("id"), long.class),
                    // You can deconstruct JsonElement recursively, but deserialization context respects Gson context built with GsonBuilder
                    // This also does trigger the Photo.Deserializer
                    context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("photos"), photoListType)
            );
        }

    }

}
```

I'm assuming `Photos` in your code is a typo and it's supposed to be `Photo`. If it's not, then a similar solution might be implemented for `Photos`.

```java
final class Photo {

    final String url;

    private Photo(final String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    static final class Deserializer
            implements JsonDeserializer<Photo> {

        @Override
        public Photo deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            return new Photo(
                    // jsonObject.get("url").getAsString() can be more simple, but it does not respect Gson instance configuration
                    context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("url"), String.class)
            );
        }

    }

}
```

How it can be used:

```java
final class Wrapper {

    final User user;

    private Wrapper(final User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new User.Deserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Photo.class, new Photo.Deserializer())
        .create();
final Wrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(JSON, Wrapper.class);
System.out.println(wrapper.user.id);
wrapper.user.photos.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.url));
```

The output:

> 1234
>   http://.....
>   http://.....

Comment: ah, that's what i was afraid of. and there is no way to merge multiple strategies (you mentioned not by default)

Comment: @Sree Yep, this is the cost of simplicity. An example custom type adapter factory than can be used to merge a few strategies together: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/PostConstructAdapterFactory.java -- a delegate-first-and-then-post-process-somehow approach.

Comment: In other words, you only need to declare a type adapter for the parent type - the children's type adapters will be redundant?

Answer (score 1):

I think the classes don't match the json file. In this json file:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1234
        ... 
        "photos": {
            "abc": {
                "url": "http://....."
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private Photos photos;
} 

public class Photos {
   private MyUrl abc;
   private MyUrl bcd;
   private MyUrl cde;
   ...
}

public class MyUrl {
    private String url;
}
```

To get an ArrayList of the photos the json should look like this (note the square brackets and its content):

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1234
        ... 
        "photos": [
             { "url": "http://....." },
             { "url": "http://....." },
                ...
             { "url": "http://....." }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This last jason responds to:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    ...
    private ArrayList<Photo> photos;
} 

public class Photo{
    private String url;
}
```

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake in the example. i updated it to adhere to my java classes. It is hitting the deserializer otherwise, so i think the code is working. it's just something about it being called from another deserializer that seems to be the issue

Comment: Where it says Photos it is really Photo. It is a typo. Not two different clases. Right?